# Nested Dictionaries/Arrays - Display specific columns within part of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, jupyter-notebook, polygon.io

I have the following data set:
[data set](https://snipboard.io/ZerHjF.jpg)

Here is the Documentation on the Polygon http request:
https://polygon.io/docs/options/get_v3_snapshot_options__underlyingasset
It is sending back dictionaries of dictionaries which is the source of my issue.

```
    break_even_price    day details greeks  last_quote  open_interest   underlying_asset
0   30  {'change': 0, 'change_percent': 0, 'close': 96...   {'contract_type': 'call', 'exercise_style': 'a...   {}  {'ask': 0, 'ask_size': 0, 'bid': 0, 'bid_size'...   2799    {'change_to_break_even': -100, 'last_updated':...
1   35  {'change': 0, 'change_percent': 0, 'close': 94...   {'contract_type': 'call', 'exercise_style': 'a...   {}  {'ask': 0, 'ask_size': 0, 'bid': 0, 'bid_size'...   642 {'change_to_break_even': -95.2, 'last_updated'...
2   40  {'change': 0, 'change_percent': 0, 'close': 89...   {'contract_type': 'call', 'exercise_style': 'a...   {}  {'ask': 0, 'ask_size': 0, 'bid': 0, 'bid_size'...   1007    {'change_to_break_even': -90.2, 'last_updated'...
3   50  {'change': 0, 'change_percent': 0, 'close': 79...   {'contract_type': 'call', 'exercise_style': 'a...   {}  {'ask': 0, 'ask_size': 0, 'bid': 0, 'bid_size'...   3915    {'change_to_break_even': -80.2, 'last_updated'...
4   55  {'change': 0, 'change_percent': 0, 'close': 75...   {'contract_type': 'call', 'exercise_style': 'a...   {}  {'ask': 0, 'ask_size': 0, 'bid': 0, 'bid_size'...   814 {'change_to_break_even': -75.2, 'last_updated'...
5   60  {'change': 0, 'change_percent': 0, 'close': 69...   {'contract_type': 'call', 'exercise_style': 'a...   {}  {'ask': 0, 'ask_size': 0, 'bid': 0, 'bid_size'...   2994    {'change_to_break_even': -70.2, 'last_updated'...
6   65  {'change': 0, 'change_percent': 0, 'close': 64...   {'contract_type': 'call', 'exercise_style': 'a...   {}  {'ask': 0, 'ask_size': 0, 'bid': 0, 'bid_size'...   1456    {'change_to_break_even': -65.2, 'last_updated'...
7   70  {'change': 0, 'change_percent': 0, 'close': 58...   {'contract_type': 'call', 'exercise_style': 'a...   {}  {'ask': 0, 'ask_size': 0, 'bid': 0, 'bid_size'...   3414    {'change_to_break_even': -60.2, 'last_updated'...
8   75  {'change': 0, 'change_percent': 0, 'close': 55...   {'contract_type': 'call', 'exercise_style': 'a...   {}  {'ask': 0, 'ask_size': 0, 'bid': 0, 'bid_size'...   1981    {'change_to_break_even': -55.2, 'last_updated'...
9   80  {'change': 0, 'change_percent': 0, 'close': 49...   {'contract_type': 'call', 'exercise_style': 'a...   {}  {'ask': 0, 'ask_size': 0, 'bid': 0, 'bid_size'...   4676    {'change_to_break_even': -50.2, 'last_updated'...
```

Underlined in red on the picture (or text data set above) is the data I would like to create a dataframe on; I would like to have a table with 'close' as column and then n rows with the close values from the 'day' dictionary.

I'm using jupyter notebook and can't find a way to formulate properly the code in python; any ideas?

so far here is my code:

```
import requests, pandas as pd
optionchain_url = 'https://api.polygon.io/v3/snapshot/options/AAPL?expiration_date=2023-01-20&apiKey=9z9LDShn----Q9sQSj'
optionchain = requests.get(optionchain_url).json()
df = pd.DataFrame(optionchain['results'])
closedf = pd.DataFrame(df, columns='close')
```

Last request throws an error:

```
TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'close' was passed
```

In theory, I would like to do the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(optionchain['results']['day'], columns='close')
```

But ofcourse that is not the right syntax ^^

(replace apikey with your own if you want to pull http request)

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first parse the column `day` in df to get the value of the key `close`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(optionchain['results'])
df['close'] = [i['close'] for i in df['day']]
```

Then create a new dataframe using this column:

```
closedf = df[['close']]
```

Comment: nice, it works! thanks.

is there maybe a more direct approach with json_normalize() or a method of df?

Comment: Great! If it works, could you please accept my answer? 
What do you mean by a method of df?

Comment: For `json_normalize()`, you can try: `pd.json_normalize(optionchain['results'], max_level=1)`. This works if `optionchain['results']` is a list of dictionaries. More info see pandas [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html).

Comment: here we are rebuilding a list from a loop which is a indirect approach, I would say. I wonder if there is not a more straight word way to do it with the dataframe object.